# C++ Builder - Using TIdHashSHA256 with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, hash, c++builder, indy, sha

As I understand Indy does not directly implement SHA256 and above and I must use OpenSSL.If I use the following I don't get any result:

```
#include <IdHashSHA.hpp>
...
TIdHashSHA256 *x = new TIdHashSHA256;
ShowMessage(BoolToStr(x->IsAvailable(), true));
```

i get false. I read somewhere I need to use IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders and load SSL library but I don't know how. Can anyone give an example how to use SHA256 in C++ Builder?

Comment: `IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary` will probably go to considerably depths to make that desired digest algorithm a reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `LoadOpenSSLLibrary()` to initialize the OpenSSL functions that `TIdHashSHA256` uses internally.

Also, `IsAvailable()` is a `class` method (similar to a `static` method but with an extra metaclass parameter), so you do not need an object instance to call it:

```
#include <IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.hpp>
#include <IdHashSHA.hpp>
...
LoadOpenSSLLibrary(); // <-- add this

// if using CB2007 or earlier:
ShowMessage(BoolToStr(TIdHashSHA256::IsAvailable(__classid(TIdHashSHA256)), true)); 

// if using CB2009 or later:
ShowMessage(BoolToStr(TIdHashSHA256::IsAvailable(), true));
```